# mySQL query help needed

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
t1
------------------
inv_ID
inv_memID
inv_projID

t2
------------------
is_ID
is_msgID
is_contID
```

I need to get all **t2.is_contID** into an array where

- inv_projID = 5
- t2.is_msgID = t1.inv_ID and
- t1.inv_memID = 1

Seem pretty straight forward but I'm stuck... Tried this:

```
SELECT t2.is_contID 
INNER JOIN t1 ON (t1.inv_ID = t2.is_msgID)
FROM t2
WHERE t1.inv_projID = 5
AND t1.inv_memID = 1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FROM` comes before `JOIN`.

```
SELECT t2.is_contID 
FROM t2
INNER JOIN t1 ON (t1.inv_ID = t2.is_msgID)
WHERE t1.inv_projID = 5
AND t1.inv_memID = 1
```

SQL is very fussy about the order of the keywords.
The correct order is:

```
SELECT
FROM
JOIN
WHERE
HAVING
GROUP BY
ORDER
LIMIT    <<-- MySQL only, other DB's user other keywords in other places.
```

Comment: Dah... I guess writing code and watching live stream from http://businessofsoftware.org/ sort of dilutes ones attention...